# Javascript -- Where are spaces required?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, before/after what characters and keywords are spaces absolutely required?

Alternatively, it may be easier to answer the reverse: before/after what characters and keywords are spaces *not* absolutely required?

Comment: `var [variable name]` would be one

Answer (score 0):

All keywards have to be separated from the other text by either space or parenthesis:
To get those keywords:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyab5c8.aspx
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [ECMAScript 5 reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

> White space characters are used to improve source text readability and
>   to separate tokens (indivisible lexical units) from each other, but
>   are otherwise insignificant. White space characters may occur between
>   any two tokens and at the start or end of input. White space
>   characters may also occur within a StringLiteral or a
>   RegularExpressionLiteral (where they are considered significant
>   characters forming part of the literal value) orwithin a Comment, but
>   cannot appear within any other kind of token.

So, `var someVariable;` requires whitespace to separate the tokens (`varsomeVariable;` is different), but `for(i=0;i<10;i++){document.write("Stuff");}` does not.

Whitespace is not confined to spaces, so you could use one of the other characters:

**WhiteSpace ::**

```
<TAB>
<VT>
<FF>
<SP>
<NBSP>
<BOM>
<USP>
```